# Idiomatic way of verifying a reactive request before actually persisting to the database

Tags: spring, project-reactor, reactive

I have an endpoint that accepts as well as returns a reactive type. What I'm trying to achieve is to somehow verify that the complete reactive request (that is actually an array of resources) is valid before persisting the changes to the database (read Full-Update of a ressource). The question is not so much concerned with how to actually verify the request but more with how to chain the steps together using which of springs reactive handler methods (map, flatMap and the likes) in the desired order which is basically:

1. verify correctness of request (the Ressource is properly annotated with JSR-303 annotations)
2. clear the current resource in case of valid request
3. persist new resources in the database after clearing the database

Let's assume the following scenario:

```
val service : ResourceService

@PostMapping("/resource/")
fun replaceResources(@Valid @RequestBody resources: 
Flux<RessourceDto>): Flux<RessourceDto> {

    var deleteWrapper = Mono.fromCallable {
        service.deleteAllRessources()
    }

    deleteWrapper = deleteWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())

    return deleteWrapper.thenMany<RessourceDto> {
        resources
                .map(mapper::map) // map to model object
                .flatMap(service::createResource)
                .map(mapper::map) // map to dto object
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    }
}

//alternative try
@PostMapping("/resourceAlternative/")
override fun replaceResourcesAlternative2(@RequestBody resources: 
Flux<ResourceDto>): Flux<ResourceDto> {

    return service.deleteAllResources()
            .thenMany<ResourceDto> {
                resources
                        .map(mapper::map)
                        .flatMap(service::createResource)
                        .map(mapper::map)
            }
}
```

Whats the idiomatic way of doing this in a reactive fashion?

Comment: I added the work in progress code. It never really returns until the server quits with a connection timeout.

Comment: I added a second failed attempt but it seems the thenMany - part is never executed. My guess is that its not executed due to no actual subscription to the Publisher but I dont know how to subscribe and return something besides Disposable.

Comment: The seconds solution seems to work but I had to replace the curly braces of the thenMany - block with braces. I don't understand why that is though.